# How can I change my external drive name?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I own a couple of WD Elements 1TB external drives (WD Elements Portable 2.5" 1TB USB3). I've renamed them on my PC, so that I can easily tell which drive I'm currently working with. Most of the time, I have both of these drives connected to my TV (LG 42", 42LF652V).

The problem is, my TV sees both of these drives as `Elements 25A2`. As they are the exact same model, I can't say which is which, unless I browse through them. I'd like to change the way they are displayed on my TV. It seems that the names I've set on my PC aren't used in this context, so I'm looking for another way. Any ideas?